# Why doesn't ion-input + angular-onscreen-material-keyboard work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, on-screen-keyboard

Hello I'm using Ionic 5 and I'd like to use angular-onscreen-material-keyboard with ion-input. However for some reason it fails, I don't get any binding error to matKeyboard, however the onscreen keyboard is not shown. If I simply use “input” everything is just fine.

Did anyone manage to make the angular-onscreen-material-keyboard work with Ionic 5?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

#tldr: angular-onscreen-material-keyboard doesn't support Ionic.

The long story. There are various issues.

a.) the keyboard directive listens to wrong events (Ionic uses ionBlur, ionFocus instead of regular blur and focus)

b.) _getCursorPosition() is keyboard-key.component is not working with ion-*, the actual cursor position could not be fetched.